# $select parameter not working on Microsoft Graph API share calendar (cURL)

Tags: rest, curl, microsoft-graph-api, office365

When using the following URL in Microsoft Graph Explorer, I can see a list of my Calendar Event's with only the subject field returned as JSON.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2022-06-17T16:37:48.171Z&enddatetime=2022-06-24T16:37:48.171Z&$select=subject`

When doing the same for a resource's Calendar, all the information is returned instead of just the subject field.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<CALENDAR_SMTP>/calendarView?startdatetime=2022-06-17T16:37:48.171Z&enddatetime=2022-06-24T16:37:48.171Z&$select=subject"`

Am I doing something wrong in cURL or doesn't **$select** work on other users' calendars?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - Skipped the $ in cURL and it worked.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<CALENDAR_SMTP>/calendarView?startdatetime=2022-06-17T16:37:48.171Z&enddatetime=2022-06-24T16:37:48.171Z&select=subject"`